# C++ Copying files to USB Device

Tags: c++, usb, createfile

I have serveral files of different types. `.gz` `.cfg` `.tar` and I would like to **copy** them to a **USB** Device connected to a Drive. This is my code:

```
//path -> destination path looking like: "\\\\?\\"+ driveLetter + ":\\file"
//i -> my Iterator for Map<srcPath,destPath>
QFile qsrcFile(i.key());
    QFileInfo srcInfo(qsrcFile);
    QString path(i.value());
    HANDLE usbHandle = CreateFileW(path.toStdWString().c_str(),
                                GENERIC_WRITE, //can cause permission problems > set to 0
                                FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                0,
                                CREATE_ALWAYS,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                0);

    if(usbHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        DWORD err = ::GetLastError();
        fprintf(stderr,"Error INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE \n \t Path: %s \n \t Error: %d \n",path.toStdString().c_str(),err);
        if(err == ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND){
            CreateDirectoryW(path.toStdWString().substr(0,path.lastIndexOf("\\")).c_str(),0);
            i.previous(); //try creating a file again, 
                          //this time with a parent directory (works only for depth = 1)
        }
        continue;
    }

    DWORD written = 0;

    if(!WriteFile(usbHandle, qsrcFile.readAll(), srcInfo.size(), &written, NULL)){
        qsrcFile.close();
        fprintf(stderr,"Error at WriteFile() \n \t file: %s \n",qsrcFile.fileName().toStdString().c_str()); //writting error
        continue;
    }
```

If I run the programm it seems that the usbHandler is invalid. Im not quiet sure how to use these WinAPI function properly but I thought this could work.
I just need to write my Files to `I:/(USB)`.

How do I copy Files to a USB device connected to a Drive?

**EDIT**:

- **FIX** `\\\\.\\I:\\` to get `\\.\I:\` worked fine. (also "?" instead of dot is possible)
- I had the Error: `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` therefor I tried changing the
  `dwDesiredAccess` Flag to 0 (I also tried running VS2010 as Admin). Its fixed for now, but that caused other problems
- Once I (magicly) got some files , but the `.tar` and `.gz` files where broken/empty. How can I write into this files when `WriteFile()` is too primitive for that?

Comment: Sidenote: Would close the file before returning in case of write error.

Comment: The third bullet is unrelated. These functions are too primitive to know about file types.

Comment: Since you're passing a `wchar_t`, you really should be using `CreateFileW`. The `CreateFile` macro expands to `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW`, but unlike C++ overloading this doesn't take the argument type into account. Passing a `wchar_t*` to `CreateFileA` will give the symptoms you describe.

Comment: Makes sence, but unfortunately it didn't solved the problem.

Comment: why `OPEN_EXISTING`?

Comment: I already changed it to `CREATE_ALWAYS` because I format the USB device before. So there wont be anything to open..

Comment: @MSalters How can I copy the `.tar` files (etc.). It's not possible with WriteFile()?

Comment: @Drayke: That is perfectly possible. WriteFile doesn't interpret extensions either. I bet that you will find the code still doesn't work if you rename the file to `Test1.tst` in your code, and then rename it back to `*.tar` from Explorer

Comment: "I tried changing the dwDesiredAccess Flag to 0"  This assuredly explains why your files are empty -- The `CreateFile` succeeds and the `WriteFile` fails due to insufficient access.